# How to strip a string in julia

Tags: string, julia, strip

Why do I get an error when I try to `strip` a string in Julia?

```
strip("Clean Monkeys", "s")
# expected
> "Clean Monkey"
# but got 
> MethodError: objects of type String are not callable
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Julia there is a difference between single and double apostrophes around characters (unlike languages like Python and R). So `"s"` is seen as string and `'s'` as a character.

Strip only removes char(s) not string(s). From the docs:
`strip(str::AbstractString, chars) -> SubString`

```
# This works
strip("Clean Monkeys", 's')
> "Clean Monkey"

# you can also provide lists of characters
strip("Clean Monkeys", ['e', 'y', 's'])
> "Clean Monk"
```

Answer (score 2):

Like it was said by @Jonas `strip` takes a `Char` as the second argument. If you want to actually remove a `SubString` at the back you can always use a regular expression such as:

```
julia> replace("Hello worldHello", r"Hello$"=>"")
"Hello world"
```

Note that `$` is an end-of-string anchor and hence only the ending `Hello` was removed.